# Change "Command + dot" (Break) keyboard shortcut in Terminal Mac which is not in the menu bar

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

There are many keyboard shortcuts on macOS Monterey 12
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/terminal/trmlshtcts/mac
but some of them are not present in the menu bar so I can not disable them using System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App shortcuts

For example for Command + dot (synonyms: cmd+full stop, command-period) is mapped to `Break` (like Ctrl + c) but I would like to use CMD+. for other things (like open particular window using Automator).

Comment: i have similar problem i cannot command + dot . mbp m1 macOS Monterey 12.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I end up using Karabiner elements.
Start by reading
https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org
than play with some of the examples
https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org
and at the end you can add custom manipulator that will change CMD+. to CMD+\ inside terminal app.

```
# .config/karabiner/karabiner.json
                            {
                                "conditions": [
                                    {
                                        "bundle_identifiers": [
                                            "^com\\.apple\\.Terminal$"
                                        ],
                                        "type": "frontmost_application_if"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "from": {
                                    "key_code": "period",
                                    "modifiers": {
                                        "mandatory": [
                                            "left_command"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                },
                                "to": [
                                    {
                                        "key_code": "backslash",
                                        "modifiers": [
                                            "left_command"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "type": "basic"
                            },
```